# Maven cyclic Exception

Tags: maven

> [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='com.wellpoint.ced:ced-rdm-jar:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='com.wellpoint.ced:ced-war:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph com.wellpoint.ced:ced-war:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT --> com.wellpoint.ced:ced-rdm-jar:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT --> com.wellpoint.ced:ced-war:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Say for example i have A,B,C,D etc maven projects, A is the parent project `i.e agregator and rest of them are child projects.`
In `Projetc B`, i have dependecy on `project C`
And in Project C, i have dependency on Project B
How to get rid of this problem.